# associative to numeric array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array, which keys I want to use in numbers. What I mean: The array is kinda like this:

```
$countries = array
    "AD"  =>  array("AND", "Andorra"),
    "BG"  =>  array("BGR", "Bulgaria")
);
```

Obviously AD is 0 and BG is 1, but when I print `$countries[1]` it doesn't display even `"Array"`.
When I print `$countries[1][0]` it also doesn't display anything. I have the number of the key, but I shouldn't use the associative key.

Comment: You want to use a string key and a numeric key. Why don't you do this with a SQL TABLE with a schema of id, code, name?

Comment: Maybe it's not so obvious that "`AD` is `0`". Maybe it's not even true?

Comment: fabianhjr: Yes and II cant use an SQL Table, because the script has a lot of modules and I'm not sure which uses which.
KerrekSB: Why?

Answer (score 21):

Perfect use case for [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$countries = array_values($countries);
```

Then you can retrieve the values by their index:

```
$countries[0][0]; // "AND"
$countries[0][1]; // "Andorra"
$countries[1][0]; // "BGR"
$countries[1][1]; // "Bulgaria"
```

Answer (score 4):

[`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) will give you the array's keys. [`array_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will give you the array's values. Both will be indexed numerically.

Answer (score 1):

you might convert it into a numeric array:

```
    $countries = array(
    "AD"  =>  array("AND", "Andorra"),
    "BG"  =>  array("BGR", "Bulgaria")
);
$con=array();
$i=0;
foreach($countries as $key => $value){
    $con[$i]=$value;
    $i++;
}
echo $con[1][1];

//the result is Bulgaria
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of workarounds to get what you want. Besides crafting a secondary key-map array, injecting references, or an [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/ArrayAccess) abomination that holds numeric *and* associative keys at the same time, you could also use this:

```
 print current(array_slice( current(array_slice($countries, 1)), 0));
```

That's the fugly workaround to `$countries[1][0]`. Note that array keys appear to appear in the same order still; bemusing.