# Convert an associative array to a simple array of its values in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I would like to convert the array:

```
Array ( 
[category] => category 
[post_tag] => post_tag 
[nav_menu] => nav_menu 
[link_category] => link_category 
[post_format] => post_format 
)
```

to

```
array(category, post_tag, nav_menu, link_category, post_format)
```

I tried

```
$myarray = 'array('. implode(', ',get_taxonomies('','names')) .')';
```

which echos out:

```
array(category, post_tag, nav_menu, link_category, post_format)
```

So I can do

```
echo $myarray;
echo 'array(category, post_tag, nav_menu, link_category, post_format)';
```

and it prints the exact same thing.

...but I can't use `$myarray` in a function in place of the manually entered array because the function doesn't see it as array or something.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It won't work anywhere because you're passing a string, not an actual array. see @redreggae's answer for how to get just the values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [associative to numeric array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782368/associative-to-numeric-array-in-php)

Answer (score 257, accepted):

simply use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: Doesn't this still store it as an associative array but just has indexes?

Comment: I think the term associative array is only for named keys. In this case it's an indexed array.

Answer (score 17):

You should use the `array_values()` **function**.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I was trying it befoere but I must have been doing something wrong. Here's the final function I ended up using... get_terms( array_values((get_taxonomies('','names'))) , $args )

Answer (score 5):

create a new array, use a foreach loop in PHP to copy all the values from associative array into a simple array

```
      $data=Array(); //associative array

      $simple_array = array(); //simple array

      foreach($data as $d)
      {
            $simple_array[]=$d['value_name'];   
      }
```

Comment: This could be done in one line with [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), like this `$simple_array = array_column($data, 'value_name')`