# Get specific key values as an array from array of object

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code:

```
$a = array(
    array("a" => 1, "b" => 2),
    array("x" => 2, "a" => 2),
    array("d" => 100, "a" => 3, "b" => 2, "c" => 3)
);
$myArray = array();
foreach ($a as $arr) {
    $myArray[] = $arr['a'];
}
print_r($myArray);
```

So, I get

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Is there any other way to do this without `for` loop? like using one are two `PHP array functions` to get the same response.

The above is correct but still if there is any other better way to do this that would be appreciable! Because the same array `$a` in my code is required to be iterate many times. If I have any better way to do this so I can reduce another iteration( PHP still does iteration in built-in fns, I don't bother it).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a function to extract a 'column' from an array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494953/is-there-a-function-to-extract-a-column-from-an-array-in-php)

Comment: It's a shame you are not using PHP 5.5. It has a function specifically for this.

Comment: May I know that function please?

Comment: Click on the link I provided above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191903/convert-an-associative-array-to-a-simple-array-of-its-values-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes (since you're on PHP 5.4, [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) isn't an option),

```
$result = array_map(function($x)
{
   return $x['a'];
}, $a);
```

But note, this will still use loop internally (i.e. in the end it *always* be a loop)