# how to convert stdobj array to associative array in php

Tags: php

I have this stdclass object in array

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [file_id] => 6 [file_name] => 1ofdays.wav ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [file_id] => 7 [file_name] => abcd.mp3 ) )
```

I want to convert this `stdclass` object array into associative arrays such as

```
$name_array=([text]=>1ofdays.wav,[text]=>abcd.mp3);
$id_array=([value]=>6,[value]=>7);
```

I tried achieving it by first flattening the array using this function

```
public function array_flatten($mArray) {
    $sArray = array();

    foreach ($mArray as $row) {
        if ( !(is_array($row)) ) {
            if($sArray[] = $row){
            }
        } else {
            $sArray = array_merge($sArray,$this->array_flatten($row));
        }
    }
    return $sArray;

}
```

This function gave me result

```
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 1ofdays.wav [2] => 7 [3] => abcd.mp3 )
```

then I created two arrays `even()` and `odd()`

and took elements from odd and even indexes of the and pushed them in their respected arrays

which resulted in

```
even( [0] => 6 [1] => 7 )
odd( [0] => 1ofdays.wav [1] => abcd.mp3 )
```

now i want to put elements of even array into

```
Id_array =('value'=>6,'value'=>7)
```

and

```
name_array=('text'=>1ofdays.wav,'text'=>'abcd.mp3')
```

Comment: Could you please highlight which part of your post is the actual question?

Comment: @rudolf_franek I want to convert this stdclass object array into associative arrays such as

Comment: Have you checked this link ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191903/convert-an-associative-array-to-a-simple-array-of-its-values-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Hope It is same as you want

```html
<?php

class stdClass1 {

    public $file_id;
    public $file_name;

    public function setName($n, $sn) {
        $this->file_id = $n;
        $this->file_name = $sn;
    }

}

$exaObj = new stdClass1;
$exaObj2 = new stdClass1;
$exaObj->setName('6', '1ofdays.wav');
$exaObj2->setName('7', 'abcd.mp3');
$arr = array($exaObj, $exaObj2);

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    print_r($v);
    echo "<br>";
    foreach ($v as $key => $value) {
        $$key[] = $value;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($file_id);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($file_name);
echo "</pre>";

echo "Second METHOD<br><br>";

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $nameArr[] = $v->file_name;
    $idArr[] = $v->file_id;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($idArr);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($nameArr);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```