# Separate array into comma separate strings

Tags: php, arrays

I want to separate my array into separate strings that all end with a comma.

```
Array ( [0] => 233d3f9b-3e8e-4e16-ade2-6c165a0324c6 
        [2] => a6c736b0-f3d2-4907-9d36-6b31adeec2d1 
        [3] => 1e693cba-d0ce-4a24-bd75-b834e3f44272 
    )
```

The purpose of this is so i can pass it to an API. Like this

```
    'optionUuids' => array(
        $options2,
    ),
```

The option UUidds can contain multiple values as long its separated by a comma in the end.

I tried solving my problem using implode. Implode adds a comma at the end of each line, but it treats this comma as a string. I want to have multiple option UUids so i would need commas that are actually commas and not strings.

Im having trouble explaining this. This is what i expect:

```
    'optionUuids' => array(
      233d3f9b-3e8e-4e16-ade2-6c165a0324c6,
      a6c736b0-f3d2-4907-9d36-6b31adeec2d1,
      1e693cba-d0ce-4a24-bd75-b834e3f44272,
    ),
```

Comment: Facinated to know what happend to `[1]`

Comment: @RiggsFolly an array_unique was used to generate this array

Comment: Commas that are not strings? Wut?

Comment: You had better show us the output you want as your description only serves to confuse

Comment: a comma that is not treated as a string. to separate the different options on different lines

Comment: So what is the problem with `'optionUuids' => array($options[0], $options[3]),`?

Comment: I edited my question showing what i try to achieve

Comment: That required output look REMARKABLY like your input array

Comment: What you expect is nonsense. UUIDs are strings, so your array will consist of elements which are __strings__ too.

Comment: Why don't you do: `'optionUuids' => array_values($arr)`,`

Comment: So maybe what you want is `'optionUuids' => $array_you_already_got,`

Comment: I just want the results of the array into that field

Comment: Are you sure you know how arrays work?

Comment: i think you just want to remove the keys from the array 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15191914/7354094
this will help

Comment: @yunzen u were right. Array_values was the way to go, fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
'optionUuids' => array_values(
    $options2
),
```

This will give you all the values but with indices starting from zero

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you want to achieve is not possible

You want to change something like this
`["A","B","C"]`
into something like this
`"A","B","C"`

With JS you could do things like this

```js
// JavaScript

arr = [1,2,3]
opt = Array(...arr)
console.log(opt)
```

But this has no meaning in PHP (in fact it has a meaning, but this would not help you here.) What you would need is a sort of a spread operator like in JavaScript

Unfortunately the spread operator in PHP doesn't work this way. It knows the `...` operator, but this is only used in function parameter declarations and function calls. @See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list