# Creating a multi dimensional Array from two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have the following 2 arrays:

```
 Array 1
(
    [0] => Speed
    [1] => Grade
    [2] => Speed
    [3] => Grade
    [4] => Speed
    [5] => Grade
    [6] => Grade
    [7] => Speed
    [8] => Size
)

Array 2
(
    [0] => 5200 rpm
    [1] => Red
    [2] => 7200 rpm
    [3] => Blue
    [4] => 8900 rpm
    [5] => Green
    [6] => Purple
    [7] => 10000 rpm
    [8] => Big
)
```

The values are matching each other. For example: *Speed - 5200 rpm* , *Grade - Red* and so forth.

I need to make the above like the following :

```
$collection = array( 

        "Speed" => array (
           5200 rpm,
           7200 rpm,    
           8900 rpm,
           10000 rpm
        ),

        "Grade" => array (
           Red,
           Blue,
           Green,
           Purple
        ),

        "Size" => array (
           Big
        )
     );
```

It needs to make an array for each label and store the necessary values into the array. I have tried merging and combining and looping. I am going wrong somewhere.

Can someone please help me out.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have tried that is not working as expected.

Comment: `for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) { if(!isset($new_array[$array[$i]]) {$new_array[$array[$i]] = [];}  $new_array[$array[$i]][] = $array2[$i];} `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$array_1 = array('Speed','Grade','Speed','Grade','Speed','Grade','Grade','Speed','Size');
$array_2 = array('5200 rpm','Red','7200 rpm','Blue','8900 rpm','Green','Purple','10000 rpm','Big');

foreach($array_1 as $key=>$elm){
    $finalArray[$elm][] = $array_2[$key];
}

echo("<pre>");
print_r($finalArray);
echo("</pre>");
```

With foreach you can use label for create new array multi-dimensional! Is very easy.
I hope I have helped you, for any questions, please comment

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Is it possible to explain to me this part *$finalArray[$elm][] = $array_2[$key];*

Thank you so much!

Comment: @JuanJ Hello, thank you for choosing my answer as best. Then the $ finalArray variable is clearly new. And use it to form the array as you want it. I then create the array with key the cycle of array_1. Then foreach all the values of array_1 creating the $ key label (Speed, Grade, ..). Then I associate the value of the array_2 to that key. That [] is to always create a new element to the array. In fact, if you remove it you will see that the final array is simply 1 key-> value. And it does not include all the data!

Answer (score 0):

Save array 1 as `$description` and array 2 as `$value`.

You need to get the array values of both arrays, using:

```
$description = array_values($description);
```

And then you can use array_combine.

```
$combined = array_combine($description, $value);
```

Related (for array values) [Convert an associative array to a simple array of its values in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191903/convert-an-associative-array-to-a-simple-array-of-its-values-in-php)

PHP Docs for `array_combine` [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

Comment: But array value only take one value for each key (look a the your doc link) - NOT what the OP wanted

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

I read the question again and I see that index are the same for array 1 and array 2

```
$collection = array();
foreach (array1 as $key => $value){
    $collection[$value][] = $array2[$key];
}
```