# Change the format returned by the array

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
$id_utt1 = explode(',', $_GET['arr']);

$id_utt = array_unique($id_utt1);

var_dump($id_utt);
```

which returns the data as follows:

```
array(24) { [0]=> string(3) "560" [6]=> string(3) "515" [12]=> string(3) "620" [14]=> string(3) "544" [15]=> string(3) "674" [16]=> string(3) "602" [22]=> string(3) "745" [25]=> string(3) "755" [29]=> string(3) "522" [31]=> string(3) "545" [32]=> string(3) "555" [33]=> string(3) "562" [34]=> string(3) "563" [35]=> string(3) "573" [36]=> string(3) "584" [39]=> string(3) "643" [41]=> string(3) "696" [42]=> string(3) "698" [43]=> string(3) "699" [44]=> string(3) "700" [45]=> string(3) "709" [46]=> string(3) "730" [47]=> string(3) "735" [49]=> string(3) "590" }
```

But I need the array to keep the data this way:

```
[560,515,620,544,674,602,745,755,522,545,555,562,563,573,584,643,696,698,699,700,709,730,735,590]
```

Comment: var_dump prints it that way. If you want to see it that way do this: `json_encode($id_utt);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return is an associative array, you need to keep the values only.

You can use :

```
$array = array_values($id_utt);
```

More explications here [Convert an associative array to a simple array of its values in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191903/convert-an-associative-array-to-a-simple-array-of-its-values-in-php)

Comment: So it returns the values ​​in the same way that it already returned to me

Comment: explode() return an associative array, array_values transform it into a simple array of the values, did you dump $array ?